# Any Efficient way to parse large text files and store parsing information?

Tags: file, c#-4.0

My purpose is to parse text files and store information in respective tables.

I have to parse around 100 folders having more that 8000 files and whole size approximately 20GB.
When I tried to store whole file contents in a string, memory out exception was thrown.

That is

```
 using (StreamReader objStream = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
          string fileDetails = objStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Hence I tried one logic like

```
     using (StreamReader objStream = new StreamReader(filename))
        {

 // Getting total number of lines in a file
        int fileLineCount = File.ReadLines(filename).Count(); 

        if (fileLineCount < 90000)
           {
            fileDetails = objStream.ReadToEnd();
            fileDetails = fileDetails.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
            string[] fileInfo = fileDetails.ToString().Split('\n');
            //call respective method for parsing and insertion
           }
        else
          {
            while ((firstLine = objStream.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
               lineCount++;
               fileDetails = (fileDetails != string.Empty) ? string.Concat(fileDetails, "\n", firstLine)
                                    : string.Concat(firstLine);
                if (lineCount == 90000)
                 {
                    fileDetails = fileDetails.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
                  string[] fileInfo = fileDetails.ToString().Split('\n');
                   lineCount = 0;
                 //call respective method for parsing and insertion
                 }
             }
             //when content is 90057, to parse 57
             if (lineCount < 90000 )
              {
                 string[] fileInfo = fileDetails.ToString().Split('\n');
                 lineCount = 0;
                 //call respective method for parsing and insertion
              }
          }
        }
```

Here 90,000 is the bulk size which is safe to process without giving out of memory exception for my case.

Still the process is taking more than 2 days for completion. I observed this is because of reading line by line.

Is there any better approach to handle this ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: what about reaaaaaally long line?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you exactly meant here?

Comment: You count lines, but lines can be of different length, arbitrary in general.

Comment: Except first two lines, all lines are of fixed length. First two line's info to be used in other lines. These files are being provided from outside.

Example:test|1234||2e34||||testdata
test1|23456|Xez234||G|1||Female

Comment: I have modified question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a profiler to detect what sucks your performance. In this case it's obvious: disk access and string concatenation.

1. Do not read a file more than once. Let's take a look at your code. First of all, the line `int fileLineCount = File.ReadLines(filename).Count();` means you read the whole file and discard what you've read. That's bad. Throw away your `if (fileLineCount < 90000)` and keep only `else`.

It almost doesn't matter if you read line-by-line in consecutive order or the whole file because reading is buffered in any case.

2. Avoid string concatenation, especially for long strings.

   fileDetails = fileDetails.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
   string[] fileInfo = fileDetails.ToString().Split('\n');

It's really bad. You read the file line-by-line, why do you do this replacement/split? `File.ReadLines()` gives you a collection of all lines. Just pass it to your parsing routine.

If you'll do this properly I expect significant speedup. It can be optimized further by reading files in a separate thread while processing them in the main. But this is another story.

Comment: Thanks :)
I followed above suggestion, like getting file content in a collection of string by reading line by line.
Removed those replace and split as well as file line count.
It improved performance. As there are around 90000 files , threading I need to implement.

Comment: @user2139242: if this helped you can upvote the asnwer, if it answered your question you can accept it, if you need info you can post another more specific question